# Freeze two columns in a table in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to freeze first two columns in CSS, so I have done this;

```
tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

but here 1st column remains sticky and when second column come to edge it becomes sticky otherwise it don't, I want to make both sticky.

Comment: this is how sticky works, you are defining its behavior. What you need is fixed

Comment: when I use `position: fixed`, it becomes choppy and looks to bad, have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your css sets stick postion to 0 (left edge) for every `<th>`. So every column will stick to left edge when scrolled.

For first column you css is fine. But change `<tbody> <th>` to class name so it will apply only to first column

For second column it should look like

```
.SecondColumn {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 100px;  /* This is the width of first column, so second will stick to the right edge of the first column */
  z-index: 999;
}
```